# Testing Azure Durable Functions locally returns an error about authentication handlers

Tags: c#, azure, authentication, azure-durable-functions

I've been playing around with Durable Functions in .NET, following this basic guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-create-first-csharp?pivots=code-editor-vscode

I get it all set up, and the function seems to be running normally (I get results), but when I attempt to query the status of the function I get the following error:

> An unhandled host error has occurred.
> [2021-12-14T11:03:44.595Z] Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Core: No authentication handlers are registered. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().AddSomeAuthHandler?.

Ive been looking around for what might be a solution to this, but can't seem to find a solution that works for me. I assume an ArmToken is related to Azure Resources, but in the guide they don't mention needing to set that up. Am I missing something?

Comment: You can refer to similar issue: [InvalidOperationException: No authentication handler is registered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51386705)

Comment: [Authentication Handler in ASP.NET Core authentication](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#authentication-handler)

Comment: Unfortunately, adding
services.AddAuthentication(OAuthValidationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddOAuthValidation();
in my StartUp did not work for me, and continued to produce the same result. It was among the handlers I tried.

Comment: [ASP.NET Core Authentication/Authorization](https://github.com/nazar-kuzo/azure-functions-authentication), [Authentication Scheme and Authorization policy Registration in Startup in Azure Function V2](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues/4397) and [FunctionAuthorize for Azure Functions v3](https://blog.darkloop.com/post/functionauthorize-for-azure-functions-v3)

Comment: You can open an issue on GitHub: [azure-functions-host](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/issues)

Comment: Thank you! Ill have a look at those github links, and if I cant figure it out, ill file a support ticket

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else comes upon this error and is a little stumped, here some extra info:

This happens if you integrate any library or project that has a dependency on ASP.NET Core Authentication middleware into the functions project. In our case, we were using the **IdentityModel.AspNetCore** Nuget library in a project referenced by the Functions project. **IdentityModel.AspNetCore** depends on the Oidc Middleware of ASP.NET Core and somewhere during its registration it calls **AddAuthentication(...)** to register services. But because that Middleware has a lot of dependencies on stuff that comes from ASP.NET Core, it just won't work in a functions runtime without a lot of extra work. So you might need to find the culprit library or project and remove it as a dependency or split stuff, then the error should go away.

For more details on the function integration problem with the specific library I mentioned, you can refer to:
https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.AspNetCore/issues/110