# Multiple AddJwtBearer not working in my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API

Tags: c#, authentication, jwt, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I think I followed other posts on stackoverflow and some doc on github, but still can't work things out.

This is my code

```
services.AddAuthentication()
        .AddJwtBearer("azureAD", options =>
                 {
                     // xxx options for azure AD
                 })
        .AddJwtBearer("enterpriseAuth", options =>
                 {
                     options.Authority = "https://xxxx";
                     options.RequireHttpsMetadata = true;
                     options.Audience = "xxxx";
                 });
services
    .AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultPolicy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder(
            "enterpriseAuth", "azureAD")
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
            .Build();
    });
```

In the Web API controller, I add this attribute:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ="enterpriseAuth,azureAD")]
```

When I call my Web API using Postman I or even just visit site root, I get this error:

> No authentication handler is registered for the scheme 'Bearer'. The registered schemes are: azureAD, enterpriseAuth. Did you forget to call AddAuthentication().Add

Basically I want my ASP.NET Core 6 Web API to take either JWT token from Azure or from a different authority (enterpriseAuth). So I setup schemes `azureAD` and `enterpriseAuth` to handle JwtBearer.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: have you used `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes ="Bearer")]` in any other controller action?

Comment: this looks related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51383781/invalidoperationexception-no-authentication-handler-is-registered-for-the-schem

Comment: Hi @daxu, when I test your code it works fine. Maybe can you share more code with us? Besides, if you use .NET6 it uses Program.cs to configure the services by using `builder.Services.xxx`, did your project is created with .NET 6 originally or you migrate the project to .NET 6?

Comment: hi @rena it is a migration